# SQL - Setar TimeStamp no Select

Tags: sql, oracle

Como faço para setar o min("TimeStamp") em um select e depois retornar o ultimo dado onde seja diferente desse min("Timestamp")?

Meu Código:

```sql
SELECT min("TIMESTAMP") AS PrimeiroLog, ID, UF
FROM bd.test
WHERE "TIMESTAMP" != PrimeiroLog
```

Meu select era pra retornar os casos em amarelos

[image: Exemplo]

Answer (score 1):

```
--minino
select min("timestamp")
from teste

--maior que 
select *
from teste t1
where "timestamp" > (select min("timestamp")
                     from teste t2
                     where t2.uf = t1.uf)
```